fastest prime number check formulae available
which is the fastest prime number check formulae available and that can be used using a scientific calculator easily. you can also refer to a patent if available. looking to use it in a software.

What do you mean fastest prime number check? probabilistic or deterministic. Do you need a witness for the primeness? What is the required size for the primes? Could you make this clear to get a proper answer?

@kelalaka deterministic

And what size of prime candidates are we talking about?  8 bit?  64 bit?  4000 bit?

@poncho 64. but anything more than that would be great. Anything that can work with this kinds easily? 336609055612707510784871435262931004779 is a prime

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_curve_primality

@kelalaka any working example you know of in python

Does the python on the target "scientific calculator" handle arbitrarily large integers? If so, there's a problem with my proposed algorithm: above the composite 3317044064679887385961981, it's no longer deterministic in both senses of the term.

One "scientific" programmable calculator that supports large exact integers is HP Prime, with its CAS mode.  Jim Cullen has posted code for that platform that implements the Baillie-PSW primality test which has been shown not to pass any composite number below $2^{64}$.

No formula (for the usual sense of that on a calculator) will do. It's needed an algorithm and a programmable calculator. I'll assume we limit integers to what the calculator can natively handle, and it has no built-in modular exponentiation or prime-testing.
We want our prime-testing algorithm to be deterministic in both possible senses for that: flawlessly tell if any given integer $n$ in some supported input range is prime or not; and internally always perform the same operations for a given input $n$ to test. We want it to be fast (if not the fastest, which would depend on many things including benchmarking conditions), and within this as simple as possible.
I propose a preliminary test handling integers with small factors, followed by strong pseudoprime test(s) with witnesses $a$ the primes up to some limit determined according to $n$ per the sequence A014233. It works for integer $n$ as large as the limit where $0≤u≤v<n$ allows $u\cdot v\bmod n$ to be computed exactly by the calculator. With the native multiplication followed by keeping the remainder of Euclidean division, that would be good for $n$ like 5 to 7 decimal digits. And at the expense of a lot of complexity that we won't detail, and loosing some speed, that can be extended to the limit $n-1$ is distinguishable from $n$, like 10 to 14 decimal digits.
Given integer $n$ with $0\le n<n_\max$ [see above for value of $n_\max$]:

if $n≤30$, then $n$ is prime if and only if $\lfloor545925292/2^n\rfloor$ is odd, done.

set $u:=n$ and $v:=6469693230$
while $v\ne1$:

if $u=0$, then $n$ is not prime, done.
set $u:=u\bmod v$
exchange $u$ and $v$


set $d:=(n-1)/2$ and $s:=1$
while $d$ is even:

set $d:=d/2$ and $s:=s+1$

[Note: from then on it holds $n=d\cdot2^s+1\,$]

for $i$ incrementing from $1$

set $a$ to $i^\text{th}$ prime $2,3,5,7,11,13⋯\,$, see A000040
set $b:=a$ and $c:=a$ and $e:=d$
while $e\ne 1:$

set $e:=e-1$
while $e$ is even

set $c:=c\cdot c\bmod n$ and $e:=e/2$


set $b:=b\cdot c\bmod n$


[Note: here it holds $b=a^d\bmod n\,$]
if $b\ne 1$

set $j:=0$
while $j<s$ and $b\ne n-1$: [Invariant: $b=a^{d\cdot2^j}\bmod n\,$]

set $b:=b\cdot b\bmod n$ and $j:=j+1$


if $b\ne n-1$ then $n$ is not prime, done.


if $n<m$ where $m$ is the $i^\text{th}$ term in the sequence A014233, starting in $2047,1373653,25326001,3215031751,2152302898747,3474749660383⋯$, (including if that $m$ exceeds $n_\max$), then $n$ is prime, done.




Rationale:

Step 1 handles inputs up to $n=30$ using the constant $545925292=\sum 2^{p_i}$ for $p_i$ the primes up to $30$.
Step 2 improves the average speed for random input $n$, by simultaneously testing divisibility of $n$ by the primes up to $30$. This is by using the Euclidean algorithm to compute the Greated Common Divisor of $n$ and $6469693230=\prod p_i$ for $p_i$ the primes up to $30$. This GCD is $1$ if $n$ is a prime (larger than $30$, but the test is not performed for other $n$ thanks to step 1).
Step 3 finds the uniquely defined $d$ and $s$ such that $n=d\,2^s+1$ and $d$ is odd. Theses quantities are used at each outer iteration in step 4.
Step 4 executes a number of strong pseudoprime tests for witnesses $a$ the $i^\text{th}$ prime for incremental $i$.
Each such test is based on the fact that for every odd prime $n$ and every $x\in[2,n-1)$, it holds $x^{n-1}\bmod n=1$ and $x^2\bmod n\ne1$. Therefore, for every prime $n=d\cdot2^s+1$ and every $a\in[2,n-1)$, it holds $a^d\bmod n=1$ or $a^{d\cdot2^j}\bmod n=p-1$ for some $j\in[0,s)$. If we find an $a$ for which that does not hold, then $n$ is not prime.

To handle any 64-bit input $n$, it's enough to test for $a$ the first $12$ primes, the last being $37$.
In cryptographic contexts, we often manipulate much larger $n$, and we don't know enough terms of sequence A014233, or even know a lower bound for that. We tend to use the Miller-Rabin probable prime test, which uses random $a$ instead of the first primes. It can fail to identify that an input $n$ is not prime, but that's exceedingly rare for large random prime $n$ (see this), and even in the worst case of $n$ deliberately made a Carmichael number, the probability of misclassifying it as prime is less than $2^{-2i}$ after $i$ tests.

My pseudocode needs review by more than me!

In Finding strong pseudoprimes to several bases all strong pseudoprimes to the first ten prime bases below $10^{24}$ are tabulated.  There are 44 such composite exceptions to check.  So ten strong pseudoprime tests plus eliminating those exceptions is deterministic up to that limit.

I don't think that this fits the Q especially OP indicated that the need 64+. ECP test will do what they need, or they need the AKS and variants... Yeah they want still calculator, puff

@kelaka:  Given the terse wording of the Q, it's hard to be sure.  But what stuck out to me were "fastest" and "looking to use it in a software," as if some light coding were to be applied by the OP.  Of course off the shelf software like PFGW for strong pseudoprimes or Primo for ECPP is surely better than rolling ones own.

@hardmath: I have made an algorithm geared at "scientific calculators", as explicitly asked. I'm not sure it would fit the limited program space of my early SR-56 and borrowed HP25C, but definitely it would have been fine on my TI-59, both from a program space and runtime perspective.

So, your TI-59 is still working, well, I need to up my commodore, given as a used gift...

is "{ [(a)power n-1] % n } === 1 is a prime" Fermat's rule a high probability check? example { [ (2)power 17-1] % 17} will be 1 since 17 is prime

@Gary: yes, but the Fermat test $a^{p-1}\bmod p=1$ very often fails to detect that a Carmichael number (e.g. $p=410041=41\cdot73\cdot137$) is composite. And you asked for something deterministic, which tells you want something entirely reliable, and/or you don't want a random choice of the witness $a$. You'll find that the strong pseudoprime test that my algorithm uses (at each iteration of step 4, with preparation in step 3) is nearly as fast on average as the Fermat test, and much more selective.

Miller-Rabin is just a tiny tiny bit more complex than Fermat, it’s mathematically just as easy, each test is a tiny tiny bit faster, and it is obviously at least as good as Fermat (and in reality filters out composite numbers a lot quicker plus handles Carmichael numbers).

x pow(n−1) mod n=1 and x pow(2) mod n≠1
